# api.ai : How do I make proper response?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, bots, dialogflow-es

How do make a right response for the questions?

After 3 conversation flow from the user,I am getting the linear response from the bot.

Existing API structure.
[Screenshot of my api.ai flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJ5rE.png)

```
eg: user: I'd like to book a room, please.
    bot:  What kind of room would you like?
    user: March 23rd.
    bot:  Certainly. When for, Sir/Madam?
    user: Three nights.
    bot:  How long will you be staying?
    user: What kind of rooms do u have?
    bot:  Certainly. When for, Sir/Madam?
```

**exceptation**

```
user:   I'd like to book a room, please.
bot:    Certainly. When for, Sir/Madam?
user:   March 23rd.
bot:    How long will you be staying?
user:   Three nights.
bot:    What kind of room would you like?
user:   What kind of rooms do u have?
```

Comment: Unfortunately your question only contains requirements - it is not showing any efforts from your side to solve this problem yourself. Please add your attempts to this questions - as this site is not a free "we do your (home)work" service. Beyond that: please turn to the [help] to learn how/what to ask here. Thanks!

Comment: I need more explanation. your question is not clear

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've mixed up intents, user say examples and responses.  Each user says example is an example of something a user can say to match the entire intent.  If the intent is matched, one of the responses for the intent is randomly selected and surfaced to the user.  If you'd like to ask the sequence of question you mention after a user indicates they'd like to book a room you should use something API.AI calls [slot filling](https://api.ai/docs/examples/slot-filling).  If you do, your intent will look like this:
[image]
You'll also need to create a room type entity. I created a basic one for you that looks like this:
[image]

If you query your API.AI agent with "I'd like to book a room, please." The conversation will look like this:

**User**: "I'd like to book a room, please."

**API.AI**: "Certianly. When for, Sir/Madam?"

**User**: "March 23rd."

**API.AI**: "How log will you be staying?"

**User**: "Three nights."

**API.AI**: "What kind of room would you like?"

**User**:"Suite"

**API.AI**: "Great! I've book your suite on March 23rd for 3 days."